# Android negative margin does not work

Tags: android

I have encountered a problem when i try to give a negative left margin to a LinearLayout.
The negative margin does not appear.
Here is my code

```
HorizontalScrollView hview = new HorizontalScrollView(context); //  HorizontalScrollView is the outer view   
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams hs_lot_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(164, 164);
hs_lot_params.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0); // set the positions

ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.leder);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams img_lot_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(164, 164);
img_lot_params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(164, 164);
layoutParams.setMargins(-132, 0, 0, 0);
ll.addView(image, img_lot_params);
hview.addView(ll, layoutParams);
```

Note: my plan is to scroll the image from left to right.
First, the left part of the image is hidden and can scroll to right to see the full image

Comment: The reason is because in previous versions of the Android SDK negative margins were permitted (up to 2.2?).

Comment: then how we replace AbsoluteLayout without using negative margins ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I tested negative margins on ICS and it is working

Comment: Well negative margins always seem to be have been problematic although Romain Guy from the android team says it works great with LinearLayout post 2.2 (<2.2 had unpredictability), you could try a couple of work arounds, if the linearlayout is within another layout, dont set margins for the parent layout and try, maybe the parent margins override the negative margins for the child linear layout and also try giving the layout gravity

Answer (score 1):

```
 ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
 (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams(); params.topMargin = -100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins should work in `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. What you probably need, is to scroll the `HorizontalScrollView` with `scrollBy(int x, int y)` or `scrollTo(int x, int y)` to achieve the "peek and scroll" effect you described.

Also keep in mind that using raw pixel units is generally a bad idea as the actual size will depend on the pixel density of the screen. Prefer `dp` measurements instead.